# Fit image to maximum resolution size

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a maximum number of pixels that I can process in my app at one time.

The user must be able to open any image and if it's bigger than the maximum number of pixels it should be scaled down to fit the maximum resolution size. Keeping the rectangle ratio.

How can I calculate the new rectangle?

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New algorithm (after editing, should keep aspect ratio):

- Assume ow is original width
- Assume oh is original height
- r (ratio) = ow/oh
- Assume mp is maximum pixels (to be processed)
- nh (new height) = sqrt(mp / r)
- nw (new width)  = r * nh
- Make integers: nh = int(nh), nw = int(nw)
- Total pixels to process: tp = nh * nw

Example:

Assume current picture is 800 (width) * 600 (height) pixels. The maximum amount of pixel processing is 1000 (/s).

- ow = 400
- oh = 250
- r = 400 / 250 = 1.6
- mp = 10000
- nh = sqrt(10000/1.6) = 79.05
- nw = 1.6 * 79.05 = 126.49
- nh = int(79.05) = 79
- nw = int(126.49) = 126
- tp = 79 * 126 = 9954 < 10000

Comment: mo inside the sqrt = mp?

Comment: This worked great for me - but it didn't keep the rectangle ratio.

Comment: Is mo the same thing as pp?  This should keep the aspect ratio except for the integer part.

Comment: I fixed the algorithm keeping aspect ratio.